# Fullscreen chromium through dual/multiple displays

Tags: chromium, lubuntu, kiosk, xrandr, xinerama

I have a **LUBUNTU 16.04** system, and I've been trying to make **chromium browser** go fullscreen on a dual display setup without success. It just goes fullscreen on a single display.

It must also be done automatically on startup. Can't login to manage this every day.

I've been fiddling with **XRandR** and **Xinerama** but I'm no expert here.

Also tried several options in the chromium command itself:

```
--window-position=0,0 --window-size=3840,1080 --kiosk
```

XRandR output:
[image: XRandR output]

The hardware I'm using is an *Intel Nuc with an Intel Core i3-6100U CPU*. Integrated graphics, which I think it's HD 520. The display setup is just **two 1920x1080 HDMI** displays on a frame. I leave the desktop as is (not rotated).
 Something like this:

[image]

So at this point I'm not sure if this is a chromium related problem or I just didn't get my display setup correctly. Is this at all possible to achieve?

From experience I know that plasma **KDE** is capable of this through a KWin script. Just pressing F11 makes the target window go fullscreen on all activated displays. However, this system is part of a network of thousands of players running LUBUNTU which update and configure themselves automatically, so changing the DE would be the last resort.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you found a solution? I'm interested too...

Comment: @donlucacorleone No, I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

For others who might be reading this now years later,

xrandr --setmonitor virt auto HDMI-1,HDMI-2

Could do the trick.It would create a virtual monitor with the resolution of both screens put together.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).